# Rails active record duplication and save failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have this error: `Errno::ENOENT in PicturethingsController#update_profile`.

`No such file or directory - /Users/Baz/rails/myapp/public/uploads/picturething/picture/49/cat.jpg`

I'm trying to duplicate the standardpicture record and save that to @character.profilepicture. I also can't get @character.profilepicture to save to the database (I know from checking after entering the rails console).

Here is the offending method:

picturethings_controller.rb:

```
def update_profile
  @character = Character.find_by(callsign: params[:callsign])
  standardpicture = Picturething.find_by(id: params[:picid])
  @character.build_profilepicture
  @character.profilepicture.save!
  @character.profilepicture = standardpicture.dup
  @character.profilepicture.save!
  @character.profilepicture.picture.recreate_versions!
  @character.profilepicture.picture = @character.profilepicture.picture.profile
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      redirect_to @character.sociable
    end
    format.js
  end
end
```

character.rb:

```
has_many :standardpictures, class_name: "Picturething",
                            inverse_of: :character,
                            foreign_key: "character_standard_id",
                            dependent: :destroy
has_one  :profilepicture,   class_name: "Picturething",
                            inverse_of: :character,
                            foreign_key: "character_profile_id",
                            dependent: :destroy
```

picturething.rb:

```
mount_uploader :picture, CharacterpicUploader
```

Comment: Try removing `@character.profilepicture.save!` after `@character.build_profilepicture`.

Comment: I'm afraid I still get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@character.profilepicture = standardpicture.dup
```

The problem with this is that it's only copying the attributes of the ActiveRecord object, but it won't copy the actual picture on the disk, so when you then do

```
@character.profilepicture.picture = @character.profilepicture.picture.profile
```

it throws a `No such file or directory` error. Try using [this gem](https://github.com/equivalent/copy_carrierwave_file) to help you copy your CarrierWave attachments between AR records.

Comment: I agree with carrierwave but here's ruby-toolbox's link to [rails file uploads](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_file_uploads)